# Internal character encoding of Java 7

Tags: java, character-encoding, ucs2, utf-32

So far as I know, when JRE executes an Java application,
the string will be seen as a USC2 byte array internally. 
In [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), the following content can be found.

> Java originally used UCS-2, and added UTF-16 supplementary character support in J2SE 5.0.

With the new release version of Java (Java 7) , 
what is its internal character-encoding?
Is there any possibility that Java start to use UCS-4 internally ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 7 still uses UTF-16 internally ([Read the last section of the Charset Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)), and it's very unlikely that will change to UCS-4. I'll give you two reasons for that:

1. Changing from UCS-2=>UCS-4 would most likely meant that they would have to change the char primitive from a 16 bits type to a 32 bits type. Looking in the past at how high Sun/Oracle have valued backwards compatibility, a change like this is very unlikely.
2. A UCS-4 takes a lot more memory than a UTF-16 encoded String for most use cases.

Comment: The story isn't quite so simple: you *can* do UTF-32 in Java.  Look at my post below.  Or Google for `JSR-204`, or `Java UTF-32 support`.

Comment: You can of course encode and decode a String in Java to/from UTF-32. But that doesn't mean Java uses UTF-32 for it's internal representation of Strings.

Comment: UTF-32 is a character encoding that turns a series of characters into a sequence of bytes. It doesn't say how Java would internally deal with Unicode. I doubt Java will ever move from UCS-2 for its encoding which is fine for most uses. The biggest danger is if there was a UCS-4 codepage then most Java code would erroneously treat the String's length as the number of characters. It's doubtful it would iterate the string and handle code pages properly either.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: So far as I know, when JRE executes an Java application, the string
>   will be seen as a (16-bit Unicode) byte array

A: Yes

> Q: With the new release version of Java (Java 7) , what is its
>   internal charater-encoding?

A: Same

> Q: Is there any possibility that Java start to use UCS-4 internally?

A: I haven't heard anything of the kind

However, you *can* use "code-points" to implement UTF-32 characters in Java 5 and higher:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-unicode/
- http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=204